# How can I speed up large web page with many DB requests?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, iis-7

Platform: Asp.Net (Website),C#, SQL Server 2012, Ajax.

I am developing an Asp.Net web application It will be used by many users (may be around 5000 or more). Where I have a webpage on which I display around 200 to 500 Grid Rows, each row contains around 20 to 25 controls like TextBox, Dropdown, Link Button & some HTML links to show/Hide information using JavaScript.

It's basically a data-entry page where user can edit/add records & finally save them.

I reloads the HTML on each Page load (as I have set the View State to false for this Literal Control). On Server side execution it generally takes 5 to 8 seconds, but it generally loads whole content in 12 to 18 seconds, but some times it takes around 40 seconds to over 1 minute (I guess this could be the concurrency issue but not sure as many times with some users it loads in 15 seconds approx.).

What I do for loading this HTML?

1st I fetch the list of combined items from DB, then I break it into hierarchy view, then I loop through each item & creates the HTML string. In each Items there are many sub Items like Getting Staff List to de displayed in DDL, also getting Distance for each Staff, etc (again I hit DB for each sub processing).

Some of these operations include very large DB Tables(having more than 50,000 rows) I have tune such stored procedures to avoid any use of like/Replace/etc operators.

Please guide me what approach should be taken in such a scenario?
Can I use Threads to perform multiple operations in Web Applications to reduce the processing time?

Thanks

Comment: Why you do not paging the 500 grid rows ? This is a WPF application not a Web Application. Better to paging the results and render a flat html table with a button for editing (maybe a popup ?) and save only the selected item. See AngularJS.

Comment: Hi. We have to display all data hence paging cannot be done. If you are talking about getting data in the background then that is a good solution but main issue browser hangs for a second if we get data via ajax in the background and when it is shown on the browser.

Comment: This is not a WPF application. this is a Web application.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a big page with a lot of functionality. How do you manage your edits? Do you allow users to do multiple changes to multiple rows and then commit or do you commit to the server after each row edit?

I think that you could employ **JavaScript** and maybe leverage modern **HTML5** features like local data etc to allow your users to edit and see the data locally cached on the page and then use JavaScript to push the updated data back to the server. By using **Ajax** you can push selectively only the updated data instead of a full page refresh through postback. That way your users get a better experience and you minimize the amount of data going back and forth the server.

I hope this points you to the right direction.

Comment: Well, right now I allow user to edit the whole content & then user clicks a button to save all the changes. Infect your suggestion of using Ajax looks the only solutions for this scenario. I tried this on small part & it worked fine as there is no need of reloading the whole page. Can u giud me how should the whole data on 1st page load.

Comment: I meant the only problem now which remains is how to load the whole data on first page load immediately. I will tell you current analytics. In order to load whole where download speed is 12 MBPS it takes 6-7 seconds to download complete data on first page load. Users who have speed of 4-5 MBPS , it takes 12 seconds for them. i want this to optimized further. How can i achieve under 5 seconds for this? The operations after page have been optimized and they are done within 1 second as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to limit number of rows per page to 20-30 as you have mentioned you are displaying 200 to 500 Grid Rows. Also create separate page for edit instead of inline edit in grid where there are 20 to 25 controls are available to edit because it will increase page size as number of rows increase.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you haven't find answer on your question here. Rather, there are common approaches for resolving this issue.

I think it is:

- -ajax
- -paging (separete your data result by pages)
- -data caching
- -creating summary view for current row (basic data set) with the possibility of other data-loading

It's first things that comes to my head.

Comment: How can I reduce the page load time when the page is first loads I have implemented Y-slow features. Need help to improve SQL operations, any ideas?

Comment: We cannot do paging. We have to show all data to the user.The operations after page have been optimized and they are done within 1 second as well using ajax. We have tried whole data via ajax as well for the first time but that is taking the same amount of time without ajax. Please check analytics below:  In order to load whole where download speed is 12 MBPS it takes 6-7 seconds to download complete data on first page load. Users who have speed of 4-5 MBPS , it takes 12 seconds for them. i want this to optimized further. How can i achieve under 5 seconds for this?